# calculate correlation using cdo in Netcdf file

Tags: cdo-climate, ferret

I want to calculate spatial and temporal correlation coefficient with a file having 1 variable and the other having 2. How can I select one variable from the one having 2 to calculate the correlation? Which command should I use? Here is the command I use:

```
cdo fldcor/timcor infile1.nc infile2.nc output.nc
```

I tried and the fault is: Input streams have different number of variables per time step! 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
cdo -fldcor -selname,var infile1.nc -selname,var infile2.nc output.nc
```